# HealthKit: Is it possible to sum two quantities by Query?

Tags: ios, healthkit

In my app, I want to sum two quantities ActiveEnergyBurned and BasalEnergyBurned per day and show it. Is it possible to do this using a single HKQuery? Or do I have to fetch them separately and add them together?

If so, How do I join the results of two query? Any help is appreciated

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
var endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

var predicate = HKQuery.GetPredicateForSamples((NSDate)startDate,
                                  (NSDate)endDate, HKQueryOptions.None);
HKStatisticsOptions sumOptions = HKStatisticsOptions.CumulativeSum;

HKStatisticsQuery sQuery = new HKStatisticsQuery(qType, predicate,
                               sumOptions, (hQuery, result, error) => {

        HKQuantity sum = result.SumQuantity();

        var date = result.EndDate;
        var dateTime = DateHelperIOS.NSDateToDateTime(date);

        double value = sum.GetDoubleValue(hkUnit);

});
HKHealthStore HStore = new HKHealthStore();
HStore.ExecuteQuery(sQuery);
```

Comment: Hi HeisenBerg, Have you get any solution for that?

Comment: I ended calling the second query inside the result handler of the first query.  Not the solution I deserved, but the one that I needed at the time. Tell me if you find a better solution.

Comment: Sure i am finding better solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

HealthKit queries, including `HKStatisticsQuery` can query only one quantity type at a time(*).

You can execute several queries in parallel in the background. This is probably faster than executing the queries sequentially.

(*) There is one exception, `HKActivitySummary`, that returns several values, but not all you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is it possible to sum the results of two queries since they run parallel. Only way I can think is to run the second query inside the completion handler of the first query, but that doesn't suit my needs

Comment: So far I don't see you telling any needs that can't be solved by those approaches. So what need do you think is not satisfied?